# PHP str_replace() in loop only replaces one item

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, foreach

I'm trying to parse a string with a php function to it will echo an `<img>` tag for the bbcode style :smiley: string.

It does work put only parses the first item found and then stops the loop. 
I need it to parse the whole text and then return it.

I tried the following:

```
function parse_emoji($string){
$possibleCodes = array('+1','-1','angry','anguished','astonished','bawling','bleep_bloop','blush','cold_swaet','confounded','confused','cookie','cry','dissapointed','dissapointed_relieved','dizzy','expressionless','fearfull','flushed','frown','grey_question','grimace','grin','heart','heartbreak','hushed','innocent','joy','kiss','kissing_blush','kissing_closed_eyes','kissing_smiling_eyes','kissing_wink','lol','love','love','mask','mrgreen','naughty','neutral','no_mouth','open_mouth','pensive','persevere','rage','relaxed','relieved','scream','skull','sleeping','sleepy','smile','smiley','smirk','star','tongue_grin','tongue_wink','triumph','trollface','unamused','warning','weary','wink','worried','yum');
foreach($possibleCodes as $code) {
  return str_replace(':'.$code.':', "<img class='smiley' src='".asset_url()."img/emoticons/".$code.".png'>", $string);
}
```

}

If I then parse $string('this is a smiley :smile: and this one too :smile:') it will insert an image for the first tag but will echo plain :smiley: for the second.

Comment: Because you're returning after the first replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you return a result in the foreach. It will stop the loop and return the result after only one loop occurence.

You should remove the return in the foreach statement :

```
function parse_emoji($string){
    $possibleCodes = array(...);
    foreach($possibleCodes as $code) {
      $string = str_replace(':'.$code.':', "<img class='smiley' src='".asset_url()."img/emoticons/".$code.".png'>", $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're returning after the first replace.... loop over all the individual replacements, and only then return

```
function parse_emoji($string){
    $possibleCodes = array('+1','-1','angry','anguished','astonished','bawling','bleep_bloop','blush','cold_swaet','confounded','confused','cookie','cry','dissapointed','dissapointed_relieved','dizzy','expressionless','fearfull','flushed','frown','grey_question','grimace','grin','heart','heartbreak','hushed','innocent','joy','kiss','kissing_blush','kissing_closed_eyes','kissing_smiling_eyes','kissing_wink','lol','love','love','mask','mrgreen','naughty','neutral','no_mouth','open_mouth','pensive','persevere','rage','relaxed','relieved','scream','skull','sleeping','sleepy','smile','smiley','smirk','star','tongue_grin','tongue_wink','triumph','trollface','unamused','warning','weary','wink','worried','yum');
    foreach($possibleCodes as $code) {
        $string = str_replace(':'.$code.':', "<img class='smiley' src='".asset_url()."img/emoticons/".$code.".png'>", $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```